# Linear Regression and Gradient Descent in Scikit learn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

In [this Coursera course](https://share.coursera.org/wiki/index.php/ML:Linear_Regression_with_Multiple_Variables#Gradient_Descent_for_Multiple_Variables) for machine learning, it says gradient descent should converge.

I'm using Linear regression from scikit learn. It doesn't provide gradient descent info. I have seen many questions on StackOverflow to implement linear regression with gradient descent.

How do we use Linear regression from scikit-learn in real world?
OR
Why doesn't scikit-learn provide gradient descent info in linear regression output?

Comment: One note is for LogisticRegression, it does provide an argument called `solver` where you can select which optimizer it will use. It will show debug information for the optimizer if you set `verbose=1`. http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Scikit learn provides you two approaches to linear regression:

1. `LinearRegression` object uses Ordinary Least Squares solver from scipy, as LR is one of two classifiers which have **closed form solution**. Despite the ML course - you can actually learn this model by just inverting and multiplicating some matrices.
2. `SGDRegressor` which is an implementation of **stochastic gradient descent**, very generic one where you can choose your penalty terms. To obtain linear regression you choose loss to be `L2` and penalty also to `none` (linear regression) or `L2` (Ridge regression)

There is no "typical gradient descent" because it is **rarely used** in practise. If you can decompose your loss function into additive terms, then stochastic approach is known to behave better (thus SGD) and if you can spare enough memory - OLS method is faster and easier (thus first solution).